# Backbone model with a function in defaults returning object to use in jquery template

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-templates, backbone-model

I have a model something like this and I want to access those object's key's values in a jquery template

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
  
        defaults : {
                name : "abc"
                designation: "def"
        },

        defaults : {
          
                foo: function (obj) {
                      return {
                          child1: {
                             childName: "Mike",
                             childAge: 20
                          },
                          child2: {
                             childName: "Tom",
                             childAge: 10
                          }
                      };
                }
        }
});
```

And a jquery template where I want to access those values something like this

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="temp1">
    {{ if child1.childAge > 18 }}      
       <p> Allowed </p>
    {{ else }}
       <p> Not Allowed </p>
    {{ /if }}
</script>
```

I tried `this.model.toJSON()` but the I'm not able to access those object values like `child1.childName` like I can access "name" and "designation"

How can I access those?

Answer (score 0):

You can not have two `defaults` properties in your object and a `,` is missing after `name : "abc"`.

`defaults` will copy to your instante the return value of a function if is defined in this way, or the properties of an object if is defined in this way. But if you your object have functions, it will be copied as is, not executed, and copying the return values.

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, at it seems that you must work with collection and nested models.

But answering your actual question, this should workd:

```js
const Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : function() {
        return {
            name: "abc",
            designation: "def",
            child1: {
                childName: "Mike",
                childAge: 20
            },
            child2: {
                childName: "Tom",
                childAge: 10
            }
       }    
   },
});

const item = new Item()
console.log(item.toJSON())
```